# TabWidget white foreground color?

Tags: android, colors, tabs, themes, tabwidget

I don't know what I did but for a period of time my TabWidget had white colored tabs which looked really nice. I never set a theme or background/foreground color in my project at all. The next time I compiled it it reverted back to the gray tabs. My application is using the default dark theme. Even if I set the application theme to light, the tabs are still gray. So obviously it was something else that changed the tabs' color. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you perhaps testing on two different versions of the platform? The tab style changed in 2.0. Also, if you could post a screenshot, taken with `DDMS`, it would very much help.

Comment: Ah, yes. It was from compiling for 1.6. Is there any way to manually set the same color for 2.0+ ?

Comment: I had this issue and determined that it was the `targetSdkVersion` attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml was causing it to change for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was having a problem due to a bug in Android 1.6's light theme (tab indicator text is white). I was able to override the default theme as follows:

1. I created a custom theme that inherited from the default theme:

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/LightTabWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="LightTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
    <!-- set textColor to red, so you can verify that it applied. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
</style>
```

Then I just apply that theme to my application by adding `android:theme="@style/MyTheme"` to the `<application />` element of my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 6):

Check this answer of mine: [Background in tab widget ignore scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409521/background-in-tab-widget-ignore-scaling/2409745#2409745)

You can also refer to the [`android.graphics.drawable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/graphics/drawable/package-summary.html) package

In your code, you can set the background for your tabs like this:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(
            android.R.color.white);
```

Comment: This makes the tab background black no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

in the `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

```
           `tabHost = getTabHost();
            tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    setTabColor();`
```

than in the listener:

public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        setTabColor();

finally the function, which set the foreground and the background too:

```
public void setTabColor() {
    // set foreground color:
    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rl.getChildAt(0);// change it if you want it
        TextView textView = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(1);//          
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }

    // set background color:
    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#010101")); // unselected
    }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#121288")); // selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreated() :

```
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

// Set tabs text color to white:
TabWidget tabWidget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
int whiteColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
int someOtherColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.someOtherColor);
for(int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++){
    View tabWidgetChild = tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
    if(tabWidgetChild instanceof TextView){
        ((TextView) tabWidgetChild).setTextColor(whiteColor);
    } else if(tabWidgetChild instanceof Button){
        ((Button) tabWidgetChild).setTextColor(whiteColor);
    } else if(tabWidgetChild instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)tabWidgetChild;
        for(int y = 0; y < vg.getChildCount(); y++){
            View vgChild = vg.getChildAt(y);
            if(vgChild instanceof TextView){
                ((TextView) vgChild).setTextColor(whiteColor);
            }
        }
        vg.setBackgroundColor(someOtherColor);
    }
}
```