# How to use an png-image as 9-patch-png in Android?

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

we wanna use png-images as background in a selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/inputfield_text_bg_active" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/inputfield_text_bg" />
</selector>
```

where inputfield_text_bg_active and inputfield_text_bg are our png-images

And there is the problem with stretching, it doesn't look nice.

Is there a way to use this pngs without converting them to 9-patch-png?

Comment: why not use a nine patch? you could use a nine patch which scales horizontally.

Comment: we don't have these images as 9-patches, so we should prepare them or better to say, send a request to change them.

Comment: You are right. The idea was (after i spoke with our iPhone-Developer), that it would be possible in Android to use normal png images.

Comment: It is. And 9 patch are also regular pngs. But really you did not provide much to begin with so it is hard to answer thoroughly. I think you have the answer though.

Comment: i used a wrong expression. Of course it's possible to use normal pngs :) But if they are not 9-patch it's not possible to display them nice if they are stretched, is it? Our iPhone-developer can do it using some statement in his code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this links are helpful for u

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial

Comment: They stated they didnt want to use 9-patch.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

[Background in tab widget ignore scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409521/background-in-tab-widget-ignore-scaling)

Basically limit the scaling regardless of the size of the view.